# Build multi project net core image using Dockerfile

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile

I'm using the reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#prerequisites to create the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

However I have the following solution structure:

```
.sln
Dockerfile
------------WebAPP
------------WebAPP.Domain
```

I then modified the `Dockerfile` so I can target my WebAPP csproj etc.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build AS builder
WORKDIR /app
# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ./WebAPP/*.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
# copy everything else and build
COPY ./WebAPP ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/out ./
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAPP.dll"]
```

However it fails on the `dotnet publish` step because it's lacking of the Domain project which can make sense. I have also added the `RUN dotnet build` step to make sure I had all dependencies and dlls and I did get a failure on the penultimate step:

```
Step 10/12 : COPY --from=builder /app/out ./
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/9b7dda771a5bf433365f513a2bfe4cfae4199402b35c95d5f81c57367cdbb788/app/out: no such file or directory
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: are you sur the folder /app/out exists in builder stage?

Comment: it does exist because the same file works with a single project solution. Its also based on the official documentation's dockerfile - so unless there is a bug in their example this should exist and work

Comment: I'm not a .net expert but I think that the command `dotnet publish -c Release -o out` must generate the output in out folder in the workdir (app). May be this command has nothing to generate. To properly analyze error origin, could you add this `RUN mkdir out` in builder stage.

Answer (score 0):

If your **WebApp** has a reference to **WebApp.Domain**, you can simplify the DockerFile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```